# Display error when condition not matched inside foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am displaying data from mysql using foreach but there is also a if condition inside the for each. I want to display a message if this condition is not matched. the code is below;

```
<?php 
    // some other codes to connect data base etc.
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $lon[$i] = $row['lng'];
        $lat[$i] = $row['lat'];
        $status[$i] = $row['status'];
        $title[$i] = $row['title'];
        $property_id[$i] = $row['property_id'];
        $price[$i] = $row['price'];
        $availability[$i] = $row['availability'];
        $type[$i] = $row['type'];
        $bedrooms[$i] = $row['bedrooms'];
        $lounges[$i] = $row['lounges'];
        $type[$i] = $row['type'];
        $time[$i] = $row['time'];
        $i++;
    }

    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
        $distance = Haversine($my_lat, $my_lon, $lat[$i], $lon[$i]);

        if($distance < $radius) {
            echo 'Display data';
        } else{
          echo "error message";
       }
    } 

?>
```

After displaying message following this code:

```
if($distance < $radius) {
```

I want to display message if this condition is not met but nothing seem to work so far.

Comment: And where's the code if the condition is not met?

Comment: I added the code. after if condition, i used else but it displays the error message as well as the data

Comment: It's normal (i think) that you should see both the error message and the data, you're echoing the result for every row you fetch from the db. You should also echo the $i variable, so you know which index is referred the result and then check if everything is fine with your code

Comment: Wait a second, you're setting in the first part $lat[$i] ecc. ecc.. but you haven't set $i variable, you should add before the while loop $i = 0; initialization is important

Comment: Thank you for your reply but   the $is is set to 0, i just didnt include it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($distance<$radius){
   echo "This statement meets the criteria.";
}else{
   echo "This statement doesn't meet the criteria.";
}
```

You should check the basics on how if/else works before diving into this.

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt work, it displays the message more than  once and also displays the data and the message togehter

Answer (score 0):

Before make sure that your datatype is define.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php

Try not allow empty data:

```js
if (empty($var)) {
    echo '$var is either 0, empty, or not set at all';
}
```

After verify mojore points, simplify your conditions by:

```js
 elseif($distance >= $radius){
```

**Like this you avoid  Unexpect values.**

Answer (score -1):

first you print $distance and $radius and after put if condition so you can confirm what actually happened...

Comment: When I do that, it prints all the distances and radiuses.

Comment: put exit; in condition so we can check that which condition is matched..